# I need to run a function everytime a module is requested using Prism

Tags: c#, .net, prism

I am using Prism in an application and I need a way to run call a function every time a module is requested. The thing is that this function will query the database for some items, and I need to do this every time the module is requested by pressing the module item buttom from a menu. I tried adding this to the constructor, but the problem is that the constructor is called during the initialization of the application from the bootstrap!

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is "requesting a module" to you?

Comment: I mage a menu with menu items registered as modules. When the user press on one of the menu items, the module clikced is then "requested".

Comment: What code do you want to fire when a module is requested?  The initialize function?  Something else?

Comment: I solved this by using stiank81 suggestion. This way I can listen for a specific event, in this case when the module is requested, and then use an eventhander to handle the requested event. This way my function is called each time the module is requested! Thanks

Comment: And the code is a simple async call to a service on the server, returning a list of objects that I want to list in the module!

Comment: @code-zoop: I only ask because there are some builtin things for executing the Initialize method for a module, rather than having to roll your own with the EventAggregator.

Comment: @code-zoop: if that's what you are looking for, I can post a sample.

Comment: @Anderson Imes: Sure, if you have a good example, that would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you requesting your module? One way to do this is to use [EventAggregation](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Event%20Aggregator), and have the modules listen for specific events which will tell them they are requested. If you use EventAggregation to request you modules you will have an event handler that handles the request event. Hopefully you should be able to use your event handler to call your function too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the Initialize function is called each time the module is loaded.  You can just put code in there.

Answer (score 0):

when using unity as IoC container, and you request the module using unity, maybe this could work by creating your own unity interceptor (Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception namespace)